# Handling Firebase auth authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need some help understanding if I am handling the authentication/authorization correctly with Firebase Auth, JS and Python.

Once the user has signed in, I capture the idToken and create a cookie in the browser:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.then(({user}) => {
    return user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
        if (idToken) {
            document.cookie = "token=" + idToken;
            window.location.assign('/profile');
        } else {
            document.cookie = "token="
        }
    })                    
})
.catch((error) => {
    //handle error here
});
```

The route /profile should be protected so I created a decorator and I retrieve the cookie and verify it:

```
id_token = request.cookies.get("token")

if not id_token:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
try:
    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
    uid = decoded_token['uid']
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: {}".format(e))
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

This is working so far but I want to see if this is the ideal situation from a security perspective. Also, what about the onAuthStateChanged? How should I handle it in the case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase SDKs send the ID token with each request in the `Authorization` header, so sending it in a cookie is not going to more or less dangerous than that.

Instead of determining the token in `signInWithEmailAndPassword` though, I'd instead monitor ID token generation by [listening to `onIdTokenChanged` events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) and using that moment to update your cookie.

Comment: Great Frank thank you! I will work on the onIdTokenChanged. What about the onAuthStateChanged, should I implement anything as far as checking cookie/redirect or let my back-end validate the cookie and redirect to /login in case cookie has changed?

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` changes when the user's authentication state changes, so when they sign in or out. `onIdTokenChanged` fires in those cases too, but it can fire more frequently, as the token is also refreshed every hour or so.

Comment: Much appreciate it. One last question if you don't mind, my token is not being refreshed every hour (even when I am not idle). What am I missing due to the implementation above? the getIdToken which should refresh the token is only triggered during login, so when I switch to onIdTokenChanged I should get token refresh as well?

Comment: Neither your call to `user.getIdToken()` nor calling `onIdTokenChanged` will actually generate a token. But the latter will listen to token changes, and will be called automatically when the token is changed by the SDK. If that's not happening for you (hint: this is unlikely), I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which any of us can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).